# Random graph is surely not bipartite

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I cannot understand most parts of this proof from my textbook. I will try to comment on the parts that are difficult to comprehend in italic.

As we know, the vertex set $V$ of a bipartite graph can be
partitioned into two parts, $U$ and $W$, in such a way that all edges go
between $U$ and $W$ only. For a given subset $U \subseteq V$ , let $B_{U}$ denote the
event that all edges of the random graph $G$ go between vertices of $U$
and vertices of $W = V \setminus U$ only. If $k = |U|$, we have $k(n − k)$ pairs
$\{u, w\}$ with $u \in U$ and $w \in V \setminus U$, and so the event (set) $B_{U}$ consists of
$2^{k(n−k)}$ graphs.

*One of the partitions has size $k$, the other has $n-k$, for the forming the pairs this follows from the $k(n-k)$ by multiplication principle. Altogether we have $2^{k(n-k)}$ such graphs because for each graph we have a binary choice whether to include the pair or not.*

Therefore $P(B_{U}) = 2^{k(n−k)−\binom{n}{2}}$

*So, this was meant to be the shorthand for $\frac{2^{k(n-k)}}{2^{\binom{n}{2}}}$*
?

It is not hard to check that the function $k \rightarrow k(n − k)$ attains its maximum for $k = \frac{n}{2}$, and the
value of this maximum is $n^{2}/4$;

*How was this done?*

hence $k(n − k) \leq n^{2} /4$ for all $k$. So we
have, for any $U$,
$$P(B_{U}) \leq 2^{n^2/4 - \binom{n}{2}} = 2^{-n(n-2)/4}$$

Each bipartite graph belongs to some $B_{U}$ (for a suitable choice of the
set $U$). For different choices of $U$, the events $B_{U}$ need not be disjoint,
but in any case, the probability of a union of events is always at most
the sum of their probabilities, and so

$$P(B) \leq \sum \limits_{U\subseteq V} P(B_{U}) \leq 2^{n} * 2^{-n(n-2)/4} = 2^{-n(n-6)/4} \rightarrow 0$$

**Edit:**

Thanks to the help of Matt Samuel, I was able to understand everything but the final bit.
I'm not sure how the final probability is calculated. The probability $P(B)$, a random graph being bipartite, is the sum of the individual probabilities of each $B_{U}$? As there are $2^n$ possible subsets, we multiply by $2^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$a^{b-c}=\dfrac{a^b}{a^c}$$ 
This is not "shorthand," it is implied by properties of exponentiation. For the question with $k(n-k)$, set
$$f(k)=k(n-k)$$
take the derivative with respect to $k$ to get $n-2k$, set this equal to $0$ to obtain $$k=\frac{n}{2}$$
Since at the endpoints of the feasible interval $[0,n]$ the value of the function is $0$, the maximum must occur at $k=n/2$, at which $f$ is equal to $\dfrac{n^2}{4}$.

For the edit: If the events $B_U$, of which there are at most $2^n$ since there are $2^n$ ways to choose $U$ after which the bipartition consists of $U$ and its complement, were mutually exclusive, then the probability of at least one of them occuring would be equal to the sum of the probabilities that each one of them occurs. Since they are not mutually exclusive, the probability will be smaller than the sum of all $P(B_U)$, but since this sum goes to 0 as $n$ goes to infinity this is enough to show that the events will almost surely not occur as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: $shorthand$ might have not been the best choice of words, I just wanted to confirm that I had understood the derivation correctly.

Comment: @LearnToMath Well then the answer is yes.

Comment: ah, I looked up the rules of derivation, used the product rule and now the result makes actual sense. haven't used them in a while and I have unfortunately never taken a calculus course. thank you once again.

Comment: @LearnToMath You're welcome.

Comment: I would gladly accept your answer, but I have one final confusion with the last part (see my edit).

Comment: @LearnToMath Please see edit.

Comment: Could elaborate as to why there are $2^n$ of such events?

Comment: @LearnToMath Try now.